# Twitter bootstrap version 3.0.0 not working in grails

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am currently using twitter bootstrap 2.3.0 in my grails project. I want to switch to the newly released version 3.0. I have added this line to the dependencies in buildconfig file.

compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.0.0"

But when I synchronize the project then the following error occurs. 
I have also tried installing from command line but failed. the error log is as following.

: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
        grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-twitter-bootstrap/tags/RELEASE_3_0_0/twitter-bootstrap-3.0.0.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

what should I do now ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tested here in a fresh Grails 2.2.4 application without problems. Witch version you use?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue by adding "org.grails.plugins" as the groupId for the dependency and the plugin:

Dependency:

compile "org.grails.plugins:twitter-bootstrap:3.0.3"

Plugin:

runtime "org.grails.plugins:twitter-bootstrap:3.0.3"

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are funny sometime.  Often I have to delete my ~/.grails folder (or at least the project folder from within there)